# Persistent 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header Present' Error Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I've tried every all sorts of ways to fix this, including trying stack overflow solutions, I'm getting

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at '[api location]' from origin '[web app location]' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

when I run it using html. When I run it on swagger, its fine (same domain I guess?), and when I run it on postman, its fine and returns said `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

my program.cs code is :

```
using Azure.Identity;
using [project name].Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUri"));
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The js and html is

```
<script>
// WARNING: For POST requests, body is set to null by browsers.

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if(this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "[api url]");
xhr.setRequestHeader("XApiKey", "[api key]");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Origin", "https://[web app site]");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
xhr.send();
</script>
```

And the api is

```
        [HttpPost("[Name]")]
        public IEnumerable<[Model]> [Name]([FromServices] IConfiguration Configuration, [params])
        {
            [sql stuff]
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "[web app]");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

            return Enumerable.Range(1, 1).Select(index => new [Model]
            {
                output = "Updated"
            });
        }
```

When i configure it in program.cs to allow any origin, i'm told access-control-allow-origin can't be a wildcard?

Any help is appreciated. Thank You! :]

Comment: The program.cs file doesn't contain the configuration about the CORS, you can check it and set the allowed origin. Besides, when you meet the CORS exception, in the local environment or hosted the application in IIS? You can refer to this articles: [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0). And, when deploying to IIS, CORS has to run before Windows Auth if the server isn't configured to allow anonymous access. To support this scenario, the IIS CORS module needs to be installed and configured for the app

Comment: glad to hear it helped you solved the problem, I have converted the comment to an answer, hope it can help others who meet the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program.cs file doesn't contain the configuration about the CORS, you can check it and set the allowed origin. Besides, when you meet the CORS exception, in the local environment or hosted the application in IIS? You can refer to this articles: [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

And, when deploying to IIS, CORS has to run before Windows Auth if the server isn't configured to allow anonymous access. To support this scenario, the IIS CORS module needs to be installed and configured for the app.